# How can I color text between single quotes when apostrophes are present?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to color phrases that are in single quotations.

I tried:

```js
chapter = document.querySelector('#chapter');
chapter.innerHTML = chapter.innerHTML
  .replace(/'([^']*)'/g, "<span style='color:red'>$1</span");
```

```html
<div id="chapter">It's Bob's house.</div>
```

But as you can see I don't know how to avoid cases like "it's" or "Bob's house". Also, for some reason the first ' gets removed.

Comment: So do you want to apply the effect only if the block `'block'` is preceded and followed by a space?
Also, is it possible to escape the `'` that you don't want to consider as "delimiters" by some character, like `\'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try converting all the single-quotes in contractions to a sequence of carets, perform the highlighting, and finally reverse the carets back into single-quotes.

```js
const chapter = document.querySelector('.chapter');

const highlightQuotes = (element, fg = 'inherit', bg = 'inherit') => {
  const style = `background:${bg};color:${fg}`;
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML
    .replace(/\b'\b/g, '^^^')              // Contraction e.g. don't, he's
    .replace(/(?<!'\w+)'(?= )/g, '^^^')    // Possessive  e.g. Luis'
    .replace(/\^\^\^(\w+)\^\^\^/g, "'$1'") // If both above ran, repair
    .replace(/'([^']+)'/g,  `<span style="${style}">$1</span>`)
    .replace(/\^\^\^/g, "'");              // Repair original apostrophes
};

highlightQuotes(chapter, 'red', 'yellow');
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
  <p>'He's considered lucky with that curse?!'</p>
  <p>Almost like he was trying to 'bite at Su Yang's handsome face.'</p>
  <p>'I like Luis' shirt.'</p>
  <p>'abc' def</p>
  <p>Foo's' bar</p>
</div>
```

As Andy suggests, you can achieve the same thing with: `/'(.*)'/g`

```js
const chapter = document.querySelector('.chapter');

const highlightQuotes = (element, fg = 'inherit', bg = 'inherit') => {
  const style = `background:${bg};color:${fg}`;
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML
    .replace(/'(.*)'/g,  `<span style="${style}">$1</span>`)
};

highlightQuotes(chapter, 'red', 'yellow');
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
  <p>'He's considered lucky with that curse?!'</p>
  <p>Almost like he was trying to 'bite at Su Yang's handsome face.'</p>
  <p>'I like Luis' shirt.'</p>
  <p>'abc' def</p>
  <p>Foo's' bar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would fail with `<p>'I like Luis' shirt.'</p>`

Comment: @epascarello I added another replacement pattern.

Comment: I think this fails if the quote doesn't reach the end of the content, e.g. `'abc' def`

Comment: @DBS I added a negative lookbehind in the possessive replacer.

Comment: Your latest edit makes `<p>Foo's' bar</p>` not trigger it for the `s`. Not sure if that's expected

Comment: @0stone0 I must have deleted the `>` at the end of the closing tag. It works now..

Comment: I can get the same result with one regex: `/'(.*)'/g`.

Comment: The first solution doesn't seems to trigger with " 'But… I probably won't be able to do it again, especially if he's not sleeping…' she sighed a moment later." (remove double quote) coloring all the phrase